# GLSL shader in the Blender GE

Tags: glsl, shader, game-engine, blender

I am currently trying to achieve a tron like game model in the bge (blender game engine). I believe the only way to do this is with a GLSL shader. I am extremely interesting in learning how to use this powerful tool. I have only found one tutorial website, being http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Blender . No matter how much I look through that I can't seem to find out how to do what I need for the tron look. How I would like to do it is by having a secondary texture which has black where the material is to render normally and white where it is to add a "light". Light being just drawn shadeless with a bit of bloom.

This is the style:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbAxR.jpg

The questions I can not seem to find the answers to are:

How would I get the matching color between the materials, so I can tell if that part of the material is either white (light) or black (opaque)?

How do I get the color from the material so that I can output it as shadeless or opaque?

How do I add bloom?

My current code (which does nothing) looks like this:

(This is just to show the structure that blender uses)

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

VertexShader = """
   varying vec4 color;

   void main()
   {
       color = gl_MultiTexCoord0; // set the varying to this attribute

       gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
   }
"""

FragmentShader = """
   varying vec4 color;

   void main()
   {   
      gl_FragColor = color;
   }
"""


mesh = cont.owner.meshes[0]
for mat in mesh.materials:
    shader = mat.getShader()
    if shader != None:
        if not shader.isValid():
            shader.setSource(VertexShader, FragmentShader, 1)
```